# Should I declare a pointer's target const if data that the target references indirectly is modified?

Tags: c, constants

As I understand things, one of the main reasons for use of the `const` keyword is as a form of documentation. It guarantees that an object will not be modified in a given context. In particular, I declare the targets of pointer function parameters `const` whenever it doesn't violate my rules for doing so. My question concerns one of these rules.

I declare the target of a pointer parameter `const` if neither the target, *nor any objects it has access to*, are modified within the function. If only objects that can be indirectly accessed through a pointer are modified, should I declare it as pointing to a `const` object? Here's an example:

```
struct S
{
    int* ptr;
};

void f(/*const*/ struct S* s)
{
    *s->ptr = 0;
}
```

Should `s`'s target be `const`? Why or why not?

Modifying objects that are only indirectly referenced by a pointer, even if it points to a `const` object, is permitted by the language, but I prefer making a stronger guarantee. As I've gained experience programming, though, I've started to wonder if my convention does more harm than good. Since my use of `const` is at least partially for the purpose of documentation, I want to be consistent with other programmers as well, and I don't know if there's a consensus about this already and I'm violating it.

Comment: Will you modify `s->ptr` value? Others understand the C code as the C standard tells it to - const, means that you can't modify `s->ptr` and that you can modify `*s->ptr`. So make `s` const, when the members of `s` should be const. This is going to be opinion based, this is your convention. The convention used by C standard is clear - only the members are const.

Comment: No, only the data it points to.

Comment: "but I prefer making a stronger guarantee" --> Its more like a _different_ guarantee.  `const struct S* s` simply means the contents of `*s` will not change.

Comment: Very good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your `f()` function does not modify any of the bytes that constitute the `s` structure: the `ptr` member is not changed, but the `int` it points to can be located anywhere so can be altered.
The `const` qualifier for `s` just prevents us from reassigning the `ptr`
member to make it point to a new address.
The *constness* is shallow!

This goes a bit against our intuition, that's why in C++ the standard
containers are designed in a way that if the container is considered const,
then everything it contains (even if this implies pointers like in your
structure) is also considered const.
This deep *constness* is much more intuitive.

Unfortunately, I don't know any solution in C that will automatically consider
the `ptr` member as a `const int *` if `s` is a `const struct S *`.

**edit**
Even if the compiler will not prevent you from altering by mistake `*ptr`,
the usage of `const` on the parameter is really important.
Consider this example:

```
  void f(struct S *s); // const omitted, although *s will not be altered

  struct S *s1=...;
  const struct S *s2=...;
  f(s1); // allowed by the compiler
  f(s2); // rejected by the compiler!!!!
```

The `f()` function is not intended to modify `*s`
but, because `const` has been omitted, we *cannot*
use this function on a non-mutable structure. (that's sad!)
So, to directly answer the question, this is not only a matter
of documentation.

Comment: The OP seems to understand that.  I take the question to be whether it's useful to program *as if* constness were deep, even though it isn't.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm wondering. I apologize if that was unclear.

Comment: You did mention one of the factors I was weighing: that you can't pass a `const struct S*` to your `f` function because `s` is not pointing to `const struct S`. I'm leaning towards shallow constness at this point in large part because of that.